# change css class to bootstrap-selectpicker for datatables select in the below code .css() not working for me

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables

in my code i want to change style for the datatables select tag to bootstrap-selectpicker class
tried using .css();
was not able to do it

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#dTable').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns(1).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .addClass("selectpicker");
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()) )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();

                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )

                } );

        } );

    }
} );
```

} );

Comment: can you create snippet of it?

Comment: snippet means that code shows your problem in preview

Comment: This code runs properly i only need to change the style of the select field of the datatables

Comment: .addClass("selectpicker") not working

Comment: your code works fine in your system but how we know, can you make file with HTML, CSS and JS, so we know what is the problem on it.

Answer (score 0):

its not working because the .select-picker is not initialized. try to initialize the .select-picker after you redraw the datatable.

Comment: Can you please give an example

Comment: I assumed that you have a plugin for `selectpicker`.

after your DataTable initialization, add `$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();`

Comment: kindly add a snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();


table.on( 'search.dt', function () {
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
} );
```

From https://datatables.net/reference/event/search